# Error in Tomcat "Failed to register socket with selector from poller"

Tags: linux, tomcat, linux-kernel, jvm, ubuntu-20.04

I have an application running on tomcat in Ubuntu So Sometimes I had the error below:

```
SEVERE: Socket accept failed java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
```

So To Resolve this I got Few Reference And I modified the my Configuration in **//etc/security/limits.conf** as below And Increased My Open File Limits.

```
tomcat    soft   nofile  10000
tomcat    hard   nofile  30000
```

Now After these Modifications I Launched my Services on Tomcat and When I was Checking Open File Limit By using **cat /proc/PID/limits**, I got the Below Values.

```
Max open files            4096               4096              files
```

So As Here my values were not Reflecting so I set Down My Values of soft and Hard Limit Using Below Command.

```
prlimit --pid xxxx --nofile=10000:30000
```

And Now Values were Relecting for the Running PID Successfully but Again After Few Days I am facing below Error.

`SEVERE [http-nio-8085-ClientPoller-0]org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$PollerEvent.run Failed to register socket with selector from poller`** java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.isEventsHighKilled(EPollArrayWrapper.java:174)

Here Could You Please Help If I need to add Anything in my Configuration. Or if anything might be the possible solution.

Thanks in Advance !!

Comment: Please tag carefully. Which of the tagged tomcat versions 6-9 up you refer to? You could also make your question more programming related (see [help/on-topic])

Comment: Please add to your question the versions of the software you use (Ubuntu, Java and Tomcat). My guess is, you are using an Ubuntu version, where Tomcat is started by SystemD (cf. [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/345595/381289)) and a Java version affected by [this bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8168500). Tomcat's version probably has nothing to do with it (remove the version specific tags).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/etc/security/limits.conf` file is used only by PAM (cf. [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/limits.conf.5.html)) and services that use PAM, like the (graphical or text) login service. Many services don't consult that file at all.

Since Debian 10 (and derivatives like Ubuntu), Tomcat is started by a SystemD service file. The values in `/etc/security/limits.conf` are ignored, but you can specify them in the `tomcat9.service` file (cf. [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#LimitCPU=)): in a `root` shell execute:

```
systemctl edit tomcat9.service
```

and in the editor that appears type:

```
[Service]
LimitNOFILE=10000
```

The second error you received is caused by [this JVM bug](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8168500): changing the resource limits using `prlimit` can cause NPEs.

**Remark:** If you change the limit of file descriptors, you should consider changing the `maxConnections` attribute of your connector:

```xml
<Connector port="8080" maxConnections="8192" />
```

and set it to a value smaller than the limit (although the default `8192` seems appropriate to your choice of `LimitNOFILE`).

Comment: Thanks @Piotr so After Setting these values in tomcat system File I would be in need to restart my tomcat as well right..?  But Actually I can't restart my tomcat so is there any other possible way...?

Comment: Yes, you need to schedule a Tomcat restart (and probably call `systemctl daemon-reload` before). In the meantime you can decrease `maxConnections` through JMX (MBean name `Catalina:type=ThreadPool,name="..."`) to a value below 4096 so that it does not trigger the JVM bug.

Comment: Thanks @Piotr, 2 days back, I had Set Down the Values for Max Connections Limit to 10k for the user and Just Restarted the JVM so now it is showing the limit as 10k for JVM Process ID.(Instead of setting it by PR Limit).  For JVM Bug the limit for Max Open FD's Should be (64*1024) instead of 4096 as per syntax in EpollArrayWrapper.java Version 8...Please correct me if I am getting Wrong somewhere...

Comment: I didn't check the bug report thoroughly, but I guess it should apply every time the limit is increased during runtime.

Comment: Thanks @Piotr for your help in resolving this issue. The above mentioned 10k FD setting solved my problem and now the server seems stable.